# how to style bootstrap toggle switch

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, togglebutton

I am having trouble styling my bootstrap toggle button. I can't seem to make any styling work.

I only really need to increase the width of it but even that does not work. [Here's a link to the jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nikk96/orx4L80d/5/). I want the toggle switch to just get a bit bigger. any help welcome!

```
<div class="col-sm-1 col-lg-3">
  <label>Show available teams only</label>
  <div class="custom-control custom-switch">
    <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input form-control" id="checkboxx">
    <label class="custom-control-label" for="checkboxx"></label>
  </div>
</div>
```

once again, if anyone could point me to how to style a bootstrap toggle button it'd be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the width of  **label::before**  to increase the width

```
.custom-switch .custom-control-label::before {
width:50px !important;
```

}

To make the checked  **label:after**  according to label:before change the size of **transform** as mentioned below

```
.custom-switch .custom-control-input:checked~.custom-control-label::after {
background-color: #fff;
transform: translateX(1.75rem)!important;
```

}

> **!important - is to change the predefined bootstrap css with our css**

> **Before change in your file try in inspect element it will clear your doubt**